# How to create feature branches when hosting manifests separate from the source code?

Tags: argocd, gitops

The part that confuses me about [gitops](/questions/tagged/gitops) is the recommendation to separate source-code from manifests, e.g. This is what [argocd](/questions/tagged/argocd) has to say about it:

> The use of a different Git repository to hold your kubernetes manifests (separate from your application source code), is highly recommended. See [best practices](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/best_practices/) for further rationale.

In a typical project, I would use [gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab) to setup a test environment and then [`on_stop` action](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stopping-an-environment) to delete the environment for each PR. However, if I separate manifests from the source code, it is not clear what [argocd](/questions/tagged/argocd) is supposed to be watching.

For the sake of example lets assume that we have two repositories:

- `foo` hosts the app code
- `bar` hosts manifests of different apps

Suppose:

1. I've created a new branch `feature-001` in `foo` branch.
2. Every time we add a commit to `feature-001` it creates a new [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) image (`foo:$COMMIT_SHA`).

How would I create a [argocd](/questions/tagged/argocd) controlled app that watches this branch for changes?

I can of course create the app using CLI:

```sh
argocd app create "foo-$COMMIT_SHA" --repo https://github.com/gajus/bar.git --path bar -p image=foo:$COMMIT_SHA
```

but how would ArgoCD know to track this `feature-001` branch for changes?, i.e. How do I tell [argocd](/questions/tagged/argocd) to deploy a new version of the app when a new Docker image is published from this branch?

Answer (score 4):

> How would I create a `argocd` controlled app that watches this branch for changes?

I am not sure why you are dismissing the CLI option. The CLI can create an application including pointing to a git revision which ([can be a branch](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/tracking_strategies/#git)).

For example:

```
argocd app create "foo-$COMMIT_NAME"
  --repo https://github.com/gajus/bar.git
  --path bar
  --revision $BRANCH_NAME
  --parameter image=foo:$COMMIT_SHA
  --sync-policy automated
```

Note the automated sync-policy being set here. That will meant that any updates to the revision will update the branch.

> How do I tell argocd to deploy a new version of the app when a new Docker image is published from this branch

The above answer explains how the ArgoCD Application can track git changes, but this question hints at the issue of updating the tag within the deployment/replicaset manifest. This is highly dependent on how you do this for your main branch. Some people will have that hard coded, others commit the `$COMMIT_SHA` from repo `foo` to repo `bar`, and others use a templating language and inject variables.

Based on your concern I am going to assume you follow the commit from repo `foo` to repo `bar` approach. If this is the case, I would suggest adding the flag `--upsert` into the CLI command and just running the same CLI command each time in your branch pipeline.

NOTE: Added bonus option here is to add an additional flag for something like `--label branch=${BRANCH_NAME}`. This can then be used to find/cleanup any branch deploys on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

So you have

- git:foo hosts the app code
- git:bar hosts manifests of different apps

1. ArgoCD your CD only watches git:bar
2. Your CI build system watches git:foo for changes e.g. branches, commits, pr's
3. As part of CI build it creates new container and uploads  to container registry with my favorite tag "YYYYMMDD-BuildId-ShortGitHash"
4. The magic ✨, the CI then check's out git:bar, and updates the relevant config with the new container tag, and commits the change, this will trigger ArgoCD.
5. ArgoCD detects change in git:bar and makes necessary changes to k8s to get new container deployed.